# How can I confirm stripe payment on server side without using webhooks?

Tags: asp.net, stripe-payments

How can I confirm stripe payment on server side without using webhooks? (I am using stripe paymentelement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PaymentElement does not support server-side payments.

You have to use CardElement and use what is referred to as "manual confirmation" to do server-side payments: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-synchronously

Comment: Thanks, But there are some issues with the look and feel of the Card Element. Is it ok to use old Charge API instead of new PaymentIntent API?

Comment: You can use PaymentIntent API with CardElement and server-side confirmation, no reason to use Charges API, since PaymentIntents do the same thing. What would you use if you don't use CardElement? CardElement is there to help take away the burden of PCI compliance from your business.